# How to put Hebrew character in Android JAVA file?

Tags: android, character, decode, encode, hebrew

For Android Platform:

I need to put Hebrew Character ₪ and some more like אורנג in string to check with the incoming data in java file. When I put this character It shows an error like "Some characters can not be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding". These values are coming from SQLite database. Please see the attached snap. How can I solve this? Kindly give me some useful suggestions. Looking forward to hear from anybody who has a suggestion for me. Thanks.[image: ErrorSnap]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please open your eclipse.ini file from your eclipse folder with Note Pad and put the following permission into that. 
`-Dfile.encoding = UTF-8`

Some more options as well:

1. For setting the encoding on a per `WorkSpace` basis, use `Preferences->General->Workspace`
2. To set the encoding on a per project basis open project properties and change to `UTF-8`

Hope this one help.

Comment: Great man. It is global solution. You are amazing... Everyone should try what Ketan said. No need to put text in resources. Just plug into your java file and it will render it. Thanks Ketan

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need UTF-8 encoding for that.

These things are a little bit confusing. Reading [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) might clear some of the mist around encodings and character sets.

Comment: Hi Felipe, I tried with UTF-8 but getting the same error. I think there must be another way as I think this does not belong to any special character. It is a different language. So I do not know what to do with this language character.

Comment: Java has a unicode encoding, so you can use hebrew characters in the code or in the string, but this is not your problem. Be sure that all the parts involved in the communication are in UTF8. Database, Eclipse workspace and the source file.

Comment: Hi GagleKas, Would you tell me please what is the equivalent character of ₪ for Unicode encoding. Any link or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may useful to you.
Keep this hebrew word in string.xml file. You can retrieve as 
in String.xml
place hebrew word here
In java code:
String s=getString(R.string.hebrew_word);
Use this string as you want..