# Eclipse Java imports weird non-Hebrew characters instead of hebrew in file - Encoding issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, character-encoding, hebrew

I'm trying to import a [.dat text file](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/osrc/tandat.zip) including both hebrew and english characters into a java program using Eclipse Neon 4.6.0:

```
String[] getFile(String path) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResource("../../../t3utf.dat").openStream()));
    String l;
    String[] dataFile = new String[23213]; //Does java have push and pop or auto expanding lists?
    int c = 0;
    while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
        dataFile[c] = l;
        c++;
    }
    return dataFile;
}
```

For some reason, the Hebrew characters are being replaced with random gibberish:

Original: `gen|1|1|בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃`

Once the program runs once, all the hebrew characters are replaced with gibberish:

New: `gen|1|1|×‘Ö¼Ö°×¨Öµ××©×Ö´Ö–×™×ª ×‘Ö¼Ö¸×¨Ö¸Ö£× ×Ö±×œÖ¹×”Ö´Ö‘×™× ×ÖµÖ¥×ª×”Ö·×©×Ö¼Ö¸×žÖ·Ö–×™Ö´× ×•Ö°×ÖµÖ¥×ª ×”Ö¸×Ö¸Ö½×¨Ö¶×¥×ƒ`

In fact, the file itself changes to the gibberish - when viewed in notepad after running the program, the characters have changed somehow.

I had a version of my program running on Android in AIDE that worked and did not have this problem.  Is Eclipse unnecessarily forcing a particular useless encoding?

Comment: Check your terminal's output encoding.

Comment: How are you reading the file? Did you specify a character set? Old `File` based readers/writers default to JVM default character set, while new `Path` based readers/writers default to UTF-8. What is the actual encoding of the *input* file itself? What encoding do you want on the *output* file?

Comment: Use the InputStreamReader constructor which takes an explicit character set and use the appropriate character set for the file in question.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Are there any advantages of that over changing the project encoding?  What's the benefit of the default being Cp1252?

Comment: Depends on how you work.  Explicitly setting the encoding in your code makes it more robust on other platforms and machines.  For just you, choose whatever approach is easiest for you.

Comment: You can use `ArrayList` instead of a fixed-size array.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401733/3817111), you need to set the project encoding to UTF-8.  The best way to do that if you'll be working on other projects involving hebrew characters is to change the encoding for your workspace:

1. Go to the `Window Menu -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace`

2.: [image: UTF-8 encoding setting in the bottom left corner]

This will allow your program to load Hebrew characters, as the UTF-8 encoding includes Hebrew characters.